# Is it possible to set up 0 as a minimum number for bar chart? react-chart.js-2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm trying to make a bar chart using react-chart.js-2. I just noticed that all bar chart example start from the minimum number of the data, not 0.

The example below, the bar chart starts from 40, not 0. What I want to do is to make a bar chart starting from 0, not the minimum number of the data.

[image]

Is it possible to make it using react-chart.js2?

Here is the code(mostly code from the official example )

```
import React from 'react';
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';


const data = {
labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
datasets: [
 {
  label: 'My First dataset',
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
  borderWidth: 1,
  hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
  hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
  data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
  }
 ]
 };


export default React.createClass({
displayName: 'BarExample',

render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <h2>Bar Example (custom size)</h2>
    <Bar
      data={data}
      width={150}
      height={100}

    />
  </div>
  );
 }
});
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kdqqpt).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To start the y-axis from `0`, you would have to set the **`beginAtZero`** property to **`true`** for y-axis ticks, in your chart options, like so :

```
options={{
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  }
}}
```

see - [**working demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-afcsnn)

Comment: Thanks. Strangely it does not work in my [another working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3jufpp)..

Comment: That's a horizontal bar chart. So in that case you need to set `beginAtZero` for x-axis. see [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3jufpp?file=Hello.js)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this piece of code to the dataset object

```
options: {
              scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                      ticks: {
                          beginAtZero: true,
                      }
                  }]
              }
          }
```

You can read more in the docs [Axes Range setting](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html)